# MS Graph SDK .NET Query all list with documentLibrary template

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

With the help of the Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET, I want to enumerate all document libraries in my root site (eg http://mydomain.sharepoint.com) and for each one of them, enumerate their column definitions.

As I need the columns, I cannot use the query "/sites/{site-id}/drives" as it will return Drive object which do not have any columns.
So the only way I found to perform this is to query all lists with a filter for the template property set to 'documentLibrary' according to the API reference : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/list

In the graph explorer, the appropriate query seems to be : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists?$filter=list/template eq 'documentLibrary'" but it sends back an error (same without the ' around documentLibrary). But I did not find any way to do this, neither with the .NET SDK nor the graph explorer.

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance

[C# Method to request lists with the template filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVHEU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API on SharePoint list do not support filtering or ordering results. When Microsoft Graph sees a query parameter it doesn't expect, it simply ignoring the unknown filter parameter and returning us an unfiltered result; or it just return the none-supported tips. [The list api supports the $expand, $select OData query parameters to customize the response](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/list_get).

> With select and expand statements, you can retrieve list metadata,
>   column definitions, and list items in a single request.

And the currently available [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter) just states:

> Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs.

The word varies is the inference that these options are not totally supported across all products.

So if you request **v1.0/sites/root/lists?$filter=list/template eq 'documentLibrary'** you will get the following response message:

> "message": "The provided filter statement is not supported"

You need to change your design on this. Meanwhile, you can vote up the existing feature request in [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or submit a new one.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I suggested an idea in userVoice, for anyone interested in the feature, do not hesitate to give it a vote. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35500690-add-filter-support-for-sharepoint-lists

Comment: To anyone interested, my workaround solution was to query all the list and reproduce the filter function with a if statement checking the list.listinfo.template property. As there is not usually a large number of lists in a site, performance issue are not a big concern.